# For XML length limitation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to concatenate results of some string data in a query using XML PATH

See query below.What happens is that the XML concatenated column statement gets truncated.Seems like there is a limitation on maximum length.How do I overcome this.

```
select SUBSTRING(statement,1,len(statement)-2)+';'
from(
select 
'update '+tab.table_name +' set ' +
(
select 
col.COLUMN_NAME +'=replace('+col.column_name+',''@xx'',''yy'') ,'+CHAR(10) 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as col
where  tab.TABLE_CATALOG=col.TABLE_CATALOG
and tab.TABLE_SCHEMA=col.TABLE_SCHEMA
and tab.TABLE_NAME=col.TABLE_NAME
and col.DATA_TYPE in('VARCHAR','NVARCHAR')
for xml path('') )  as statement
from information_schema.TABLES as tab
) as x
where statement is not null
```

Comment: Is it concatenated when you pull data back from an application, or in SSMS?

Comment: How are you executing the above? If it's in SSMS then there is a limit to the number of characters that it will display. That can be changed with an option.

Comment: I apparently can't edit my comments here; I meant to say __truncated__, not concatenated.

Comment: It is in SSMS- following cory's suggestion I have changed the limit in SSMS and it works fine.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're seeing the truncation in SSMS, change your maximum character settings in SSMS's options:

- Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Text > Maximum number of characters displayed in each column

  ```
  (limit is 8192 characters)
  ```
- Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid > Maximum Characters Retrieved

  ```
  Non XML data limit is 65535 characters
  XML data limit is Unlimited
  ```

Comment: Using Sql Server 2012 Managment studio I had to restart SSMS to make the new XML settings take effect.

Comment: What if the reuslts are being truncated in an email being sent via DB Mail?