# Full xml is not coping from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I am using query

```
SELECT (
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
FOR XML RAW ('---'), Root('--') ) as XML
```

to get query result in XML then I need to copy this xml from result to in txt file, but when I try to copy it, not all the xml is copied. Query returns almost 500000 rows, when I convert it to xml and tried to copy.

Please help me how I can copy full xml.

Comment: If you are running this in SSMS then you may need to [change your maximum character settings in SSMS's options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3113402/1048425) as I think by default it will truncate the output. You could also just [export to a flat file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7148610/1048425) avoiding the need to copy and paste.

Comment: thanks  GarethD 
  its working.