# SQL - Transpose one column to row with delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Transposing one column to a row.

I've obtained a list of email addresses using the following query:

```
select 
    user_login.email_address
from 
    user.login with(nolock)
```

Example of results are as follows:

```
Email
--------------------
abc@helloworld.com    
no_email    
romeo@abc.com.au  
Juliet@abc.com.au
```

What I would like to do is run the query, transpose and get results as Text (with semi-colons in between results), so I can automatically paste the results into an email like below:

Desired result:

```
abc@helloworld.com; romeo@aboc.com.au; juliet@abc.com.au
```

I tried to understand the PIVOT and UNPIVOT functions, but I'm just lost in how I can insert semicolons in between results. Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: please tag which dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server

```
select top 1
EMAIL = 
 STUFF((    SELECT '; '+ a.email_address AS [text()]  
FROM email_address a 
FOR XML PATH('') 
), 1, 1,'') 
from email_address
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Reworked the script and it's returning in the format I wanted but there obviously a limit to line.  It's cutting off the results.  There's approximately 100+ email that I need to transpose.  Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: You could partition it by parts, for instance, get a-f, g-m, n-q, r-z;

Comment: also; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113360/for-xml-length-limitation

Comment: Got it working. Used script to grid instead of text. Thanks Kuya.

Answer (score 0):

you can use STUFF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql

https://sqlwhisper.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/stuff-and-for-xml-path-for-string-concatenation/

```
select distinct sno ,
STUFF((Select ','+Scity
from @Test T1
where T1.sno=T2.sno
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') from @Test T2
```